# Need help counting childNodes

Tags: javascript

With this HTML:

```
<p id="child"><span id="grandchild"></span></p>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("child").childNodes;
console.log(x.length);
```

I get `1`. With this HTML instead:

```
<p id="child"><span id="grandchild">hi</span></p>
```

I get `1` as well. I was expecting `2`.

In the first HTML snippet, I expected `1` because of the `span` element. In the second snippet, I was expecting `2` because there's not just the `span` element, but also the `hi` text node.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What did you get for the second one? One? Three?

Comment: I got one child node for each of the first two lines

Comment: I edited your question to hopefully disambiguate what you meant. Is my edit correct?

Comment: @icktoofay yes you did, thanks kind sir - upvote for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child nodes refers only to the direct nodes under.

```
<p id ="child"><span id="grandchild">hi</span></p> //1 child node

Only 1 child node is counted because "hi" is not a child of p#child it is the child of <span>
```

If you want to countall the descendants you have to do it recursively, please see below sample:

```
function countChild(p)
{
    var ctr = p.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=0;i<p.childNodes.length;i++)
    {     
       ctr += countChild(p.childNodes[i]);    
    }
    return ctr;    
}
var x = document.getElementById("child");
alert(countChild(x));
```

Comment: you don't need a function to do this, check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9090416/908879

Comment: based on my test, getElementsByTagName will only return the number of elements with <tag> it will not count #text like "hi".

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Thanks to clarify that, I have now deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy in the first example looks like this:

- `<p id="child">`

  - `<p id="grandchild">`

The hierarchy in the second example looks like this:

- `<p id="child">`

  - `<p id="grandchild">`

    - text node: `hi`

`childNodes` only contains direct descendants, and each time, `child`'s only direct child is `grandchild`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using IDs improperly.  You want to assign them classes, if you're counting classes.  Each ID needs to be unique in the DOM

Try something to the tune of:

```
<p id ="child1"><span id="grandchild"></span></p> //1 child node
<p id ="child2"><span id="grandchild">hi</span></p> //1 child node

var x = document.getElementById("child2").childNodes;
document.write(x.length);
```

Comment: The first two lines are on separate HTML pages.

Comment: @Tim: If you read the question, it refers to two examples. It contains a snippet of JavaScript code and two similar, though different, pieces of HTML code. They're kind of smushed together, but it only makes sense that they'd be placed in separate pages while testing, given that they're illegal when together.

Comment: @icktoofay It made no sense to me that way. The way I read it, it looks like they're on the same page. I don't think that's how the OP meant it based on his edit.

Comment: @Tim: I think the edit was to make the question make sense should you decide to interpret it as that both were on the same page.

Comment: @icktoofay I think that if the OP were to edit the question, they would edit it for clarity of what they were actually asking, not for a strange interpretation of what someone thought they were asking.  Regardless, if they did edit it for that reason, they still didn't correct the DOM issue with there being two "child" IDs. That only supports my answer more. OP needs to pay attention to details, cleaning up those errors will help him troubleshoot better, allow for him to test further by eliminating variables (not in the programming sense).

Comment: @Tim: I have edited the question to reflect what I believed the question to be and left a comment to the user asking if the edit is correct. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully we'll get an answer.  Good on you for taking the extra step for clarity!  It'll help people in the future.